# Karate- Getting NoClassDefFoundError when running the Test Runner as Junit

Tags: java, soap, junit, karate, runner

```
I am getting the below error when i run the test runner class as a junit test.I am using Java 1.8 U212 ...and just trying to run a dummy Soap project...has anyone come across this error?
```

**Below is the Test Runner class that i am using:**
    package APITest;
    //@RunWith(Karate.class)
    @KarateOptions(features = "classpath:/hicaps_go_blackbox_integration_tests-claims_business_tests/src/test/java/APITest/SoapTest.feature", tags = "@SoapTest")

```
public class SoapTestRunner {

    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        //List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>(); paths.add(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/java/tests/"); 
        //Results results = Runner.parallel(null, paths, 5, "target/surefire-reports");
        Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(), 2, "target/surefire-reports");
        assertTrue(results.getErrorMessages(), results.getFailCount() == 0);
        generateReport(results.getReportDir());
    }

    public void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
        Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] { "json" }, true);
        List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
        jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "Karate_POC-master");
        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
    }

}
```

Below is the error returned:

```
**Runtime Error:**

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intuit/karate/Runner
    at APITest.SoapTestRunner.testParallel(SoapTestRunner.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intuit.karate.Runner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading your Karate version to 0.9.5.RC5

Comment: Appreciate the prompt reply Peter... Thank you. Actually my gradle project is pointing to the organisation owned artifactory for downloading the dependencies ...and karate 09.5.RC5 is not available in the repository. However Karate 0.9.5.RC4 is available ...will that work in resolving the above error?   Thanks!